# How to keep window above all other apps?

Tags: front-end

You can make a notebook or palette hover above all other mathematica windows with the option WindowFloating:

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], WindowFloating -> True]
```

***But can I make it stay above all open windows (non-mathematica apps) on a Mac?***

Motivation: I want to make mathematica tool for assisting with other apps like Xcode
Note: I'm running Mathematica 10 on OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: I don't dare say there's no way within Mathematica lest someone come and prove me wrong.  But it's probably better to look for this outside of Mathematica (third party software that makes the window stay on top).  Asking on Apple.SE or SuperUser *might* be better.

Comment: I agree with Szabolcs, this is something that the window manager / operating system ought to deal with. Searching for "window always on top mac" turns up a program called [Afloat](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/22237/afloat) that you could try.

Comment: I've played with Afloat before, it's deprecated or at least doesn't play well with 50% apps. @Rahul

Comment: @Szabolcs Couldn't one make use of ProcessLink or Run to inspect and then alter the NSWindows?

Comment: @user5601 But then it only becomes a Mathematica question at the point when you know what to `Run`.  Not that you can't ask this question here.  But I suspect that it's easier to find people who know the answer on other sites.

Comment: Fyi Afloat doesn't work with Mathematica because SIMBL requires an application compatible with applescript (usually cocoa apps) for the code injection to happen. Mathematica doesn't seem to use native cocoa for the frontend.