# Floating Notebook

Tags: notebooks

I want to make notebooks that float above other windows. The expression below creates a Notebook that floats above other *Notebooks,* but not above other windows (documents, etc.). Can it be done?

```
CreateWindow[WindowFloating -> True, WindowTitle -> "floats"]
```

Comment: I think this might be OS dependent, but at least on macOS I think a window can only float above windows from the same application. At least that's what I remember from working with python's GUI system as well.

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 10.  I use couple of different text editors, TextPad, and UltraEdit, that can be set to stay on top of everything. So it can be done.

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe sorry but no.  That behavior is not end user configurable.

Comment: I guess, you can create the Window which is independent of Mathematica using the methods of .NET. Creating the form object with system resources you can make it truly floating..

Comment: Humm.  I try to figure out how to do that.

Comment: An earlier question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67310/280